# read() is not blocking in socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I have a server that sends data to a client every 5 seconds. I want the client to block on read() until the server sends some data and then print it. I know read () is blocking by default. My problem is that my client is not blocking on read(). This is very odd and this does not seem to be a normal issue.

My code prints "Nothing came back" in an infinite loop. I am on a linux machine, programming in c. My code snippet is below. Please advice.

```
while(1)
{
    n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE);
    if ( n > 0) 
    {
        recvline[n] = 0;    
        if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF)
            printf("fputs error");
    }
    else if(n == 0)
        printf("Nothing came back");
    else if (n < 0)
        printf("read error");
}
return;
```

Comment: Have you checked that the connection is open (i.e `sockfd` is valid)?

Comment: A return value of 0 from `read()` means the other end (the server) closed the socket.

Comment: @Ed Heal : Yes, it is valid. I have a check for that.

Comment: @Greg : Well, the thing is that the server sends data every 5 seconds. Unless the client waits for the server to send, it will get 0 each time.

Comment: No it won't. Zero means the peer closed the connection. It never means there was no data. In blocking mode read() will block; in non-blocking mode if there is no data it will return -1 with errno set to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK depending in your platform.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There may be several cause and  several exceptions are possible at different place:

1. check socket where you create:

   > ```
   > sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);  
   > if (sockfd==-1) {
   >     perror("Create socket");
   > }
   > ```
2. You and also enable blocking mode explicitly before use it:

   > ```
   > // Set the socket I/O mode: In this case FIONBIO  
   > // enables or disables the blocking mode for the   
   > // socket based on the numerical value of iMode.  
   > // If iMode = 0, blocking is enabled;   
   > // If iMode != 0, non-blocking mode is enabled.
   > ioctl(sockfd, FIONBIO, &iMode);
   > ```

   or you can use [`setsockopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) as below:

   ```
    struct timeval t;    
    t.tv_sec = 0;
    tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(
         sockfd,     // Socket descriptor
         SOL_SOCKET, // To manipulate options at the sockets API level
         SO_RCVTIMEO,// Specify the receiving or sending timeouts 
         const void *(&t), // option values
         sizeof(t) 
     );
   ```
3. Check Read function call (Reason of bug)

   > ```
   > n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE);
   > if(n < 0){  
   >     perror("Read Error:");
   > }
   > ```
4. Also **check server code**!:

   > 1. May your server send some blank(non-printable, null, enter) charter(s). And your are unaware of this. Bug you server code too.
   > 2. Or your **server terminated before your client can read**.
5. **One more interesting thing**, Try to understand:

   > When you call N `write()` at server its not necessary there should be N `read()` call at other side.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate reply, man. I shall try bug fixing the server also and see if it is sending some wierd stuff.

Comment: Blocking mode is the default: you don't have to set it explicitly. The code in (2) that calls setsockopt() with arguments of &0 and sizeof(sockfd) is complete nonsense and will not compile. Downvote.

Comment: @EJP : I know default mode is blocking. I just wanted to say how to explicitly set blocking mode(or reset to blocking mode). FOR COMPILE ERROR: I corrected the code of setsock() option and My REQUEST to you : please verify and if its a still wrong Please rectify so that one can get correct help..Thanks EJP!

Comment: Make also sure that your receive-buffer and its size is "initialized" correctly. E.g in this case `recvline` and `MAXLINE`

Answer (score 4):

What Greg Hewgill already wrote as a comment: An EOF (that is, an explicit stop of writing, be it via `close()` or via `shutdown()`) will be communicated to the receiving side by having `recv()` return 0. So if you get 0, you know that there won't be any data and you can terminate the reading loop.

If you had non-blocking enabled and there are no data, you will get `-1` and `errno` will be set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: I dont think this is the problem. The server is in a infinite loop, it keeps sending data to the client every 5 seconds. The server, bydesign, is not supposed to shut down at all.

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of MAXLINE?

If the value is 0, then it will return 0 as well.
Otherwise, as Grijesh Chauhan mention, set it explcitly to blocking.

Or, you may also consider using recv() where blocking and non-blocking can be specified.
It has the option, MSG_WAITALL, where it will block until all bytes arrived.

```
n = recv(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL);
```