# Should I read N times when I write N times at server side

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

Server like this:

```
char buf[10];                                                               
memset(buf, 0, 10);
write(sock, "te", 2); 
write(sock, "ab", 2);
```

Client side:

```
char buf[5] = {0};
read(connfd, buf, 5);
```

I mean 5 if less then 2 + 2, but result shows that I only received 2 bytes which is "te".
this linke [read() is not blocking in socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773509/read-is-not-blocking-in-socket-programming)  has told me that

> When you call N write() at server its not necessary there should be N
>   read() call at other side.

What is wrong with my understand or code? Should I use another system call or something else.

Comment: Keep reading until you know you received all data.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Which type of sockets you use? UNIX or TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using stream oriented sockets, like TCP, there is no guarantee whatsoever about the number of read and write. That means one write can be read with multiple read, and multiple write can be read with a single read. Usually you will have one read for each write if the writes are short and spaced, but there is no guarantee. Here you only read 2 bytes. That may happen, you just need one or two more calls to read. Note that if you are using the loopback interface, read and write calls may be closely matching, so you may have exactly one read call for each write, but again you can't be sure. The usual pattern is to keep reading in a loop until you got the number of bytes required.

If you are using datagram oriented socket, like UDP, one write will be exactly one read (if transmission was successful), and if the read buffer supplied is too short, some data is discarded.

Comment: What is loopback interface?

Comment: @JasonYang The loopback interface is when you redirect on your own machine. It's the interface you use when you connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` .

Answer (score 0):

[read()](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?read+2) will return how many bytes were read. In the case where you always know how much data to expect, you want to read(), then check the return to verify the full amount was read. If it wasn't, read again until you've received the rest of the data you were expecting.